# SQL - Select max date lines per column value

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following fields:

```
Risk|Date|Value
---------------
A|2019-04-23|3
A|2019-04-23|5
A|2019-06-12|4
A|2019-06-12|1
B|2019-05-22|7
B|2019-05-22|5
B|2019-03-13|4
C|2019-01-03|3
```

I would like to get all the lines that accomplish: its date value is the maximum along all the date values of that specific risk. The output would be:

```
Risk|Date|Value
---------------
A|2019-06-12|4
A|2019-06-12|1
B|2019-05-22|7
B|2019-05-22|5
C|2019-01-03|3
```

For the risk A, 2019-06-12 is the max date. Thus, all the lines with that date are sent to the output.

For the risk B, 2019-05-22 is the max date. Thus, all the lines with that date are sent to the output.

For the risk C, 2019-01-03 is the max date. Thus, all the lines with that date are sent to the output.

Any suggestion?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use corelated subquery

```
select t1.* from tbale t1
where t1.date=(select max(t2.date) from table t2 where t1.risk=t2.riks)
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way filters in the `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.risk = t.risk);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `analytical/windowing function` to achieve this. Syntax may vary from database to database, but in `Hive`, it looks like this:

```
SELECT 
x.risk, x.date, x.value 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        risk, date, value,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY risk ORDER BY date DESC) AS risk_rank
    FROM 
        table_name
) x
WHERE x.risk_rank = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Risk, date, value 
from
  (select *, dense_rank() over(partition by risk order by date desc) as K 
   from Max_date
  ) as T 
where K=1
```